# PowerShell module changes not visible

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm confused as to how PowerShell modules work.

I have downloaded and copied a module from a blogger. I've unblocked and extracted the .zip to %USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SomeModule

In this folder is a .NET assembly that the module uses, but doesn't not contain compiled CmdLets. Instead, the commands are functions in a .psm1 file and a .psd1 file describes the manifest.

If I open PowerShell, the functions are available and work but I want to add my own function, so I have added it, however I cannot see it. I've restarted all PowerShell instances, removed the module and imported it again.

As a test, I renamed an existing, working function. Interestingly, after remove and import the function disappears instead of adopting its new name. If I rename it back (just a single character change) and remove/import then it appears again.

I use `help blahblah` to list all commands in a set, since they all have the same prefix. The manifest exports all (*) functions. Clearly I don't understand how these type of script modules work, the functions are all listed even after I run Remove-Module! I've written a compiled module before in C# and that worked as expected.

What's going on? Why does renaming a function cause it to vanish? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. This line appears in some stuff I overlooked in the .psm1 file.

`Export-ModuleMember X, Y, Z`

So, I guess the manifest can overrule this or replace the need for it in a script? Who knows. Anyway, hope this helps someone.

Comment: Correct, the module manifest is able to overrule what the Export-ModuleMember specifies or you can think of it as being able to constrain the available members more. However, it can't broaden the available members (ie export a private member not exported by Export-ModuleMember) IIRC.